# WE8DEC into CL8MSWIN1251

Tags: sql, plsql

есть источник с настройками ниже:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   CIS
NLS_CURRENCY    ?.
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    CIS
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  , 
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD.MM.RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET    WE8DEC
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   ?.
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  UTF8
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

приёмник с настройками:

```
NLS_LANGUAGE    AMERICAN
NLS_TERRITORY   CIS
NLS_CURRENCY    р.
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY    CIS
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS  , 
NLS_CALENDAR    GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT DD.MM.RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE   AMERICAN
NLS_CHARACTERSET    CL8MSWIN1251
NLS_SORT    BINARY
NLS_TIME_FORMAT HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT    DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT  HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY   р.
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET  AL16UTF16
NLS_COMP    BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS    BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP FALSE
```

Рабочий вариант:
В базе с источнике создаётся вьюшка, в которой все текстовые поля конвертируются в RAW

```
select ... UTL_RAW.cast_to_raw(text_column) raw_column ... from...
```

В приемнике создаётся ДБ Линк и вьюшка

```
select ...UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(raw_column) text_column ... from ...@DBLink_name;
```

Вопрос заключается в том: как затянуть текст на кириллице из источника в приёмник, не создавая при этом на источнике объекты БД.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with src as 
(
SELECT /*+ driving_site(c) no_merge*/
       utl_raw.cast_to_raw@dblink(grid) grid
  FROM tbl_src@dblink c
)
select /*+ driving_site(d) use_nl(s) */
       nvl2(grid, UTL_RAW.cast_to_varchar2(UTL_RAW.convert(s.grid,'AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251','AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8ISO8859P5')), null) grid
       from dual d, src s
;
```